# Python list true false statement

Tags: python, list, file

I have question about python list, how can iterate backwards by setting buffer on list? I mean keep it in memory if path is not true, then iterate again?
My code example:

```
def clientthread(conn): 
    #Infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
    # Array of input data, check for complete transaction from PID


    while True:
        # Recive true data 
        data = conn.recv(4069)  
        newpid = os.fork()
        if newpid == 0:
            child()
        else:
            bufsize = 0
            input_data = []
            input_miss = []
            if data:
                # Check data
                pids = (os.getpid(), newpid)
                print "Parent: %d, Child: %d" % pids
                # Split line
                word = data.split(';')     
                if word[0] == "START":
                    channel     = word[2]
                    fileName    = word[6].rstrip()
                    yearMonth   = word[3]
                    channelID   = word[1]
                    videoStart  = word[5]
                    day         = word[4] 
                    file_name   = path_images+channel+'/'+yearMonth+'/'+day+'/'+fileName+'/'+fileName+'.txt'
                    create_file = open(file_name,'w+', bufsize)

                elif word[0] == "END":
                    # End loop if come END   
                    break

                else:
                    if pids:
                        slika = path_images+channel+'/'+yearMonth+'/'+day+'/'+fileName+'/'+fileName+'_'+word[0]+".jpg"
                        input_data.append(slika)

                # Loop for reading images from buffer, and try to make hash on each, if fails stay opened till END come, on succed remove from array
                for image in input_data:
                    if os.path.exists(image):
                        #print image
                        hash1 = pHash.imagehash(image)
                        #print hash1
                        print >> create_file ,fileName+","+channelID+","+yearMonth+","+word[0]+","+str(hash1)+","+word[1].rstrip()+","+videoStart                  
                        input_data.remove(image) 

                        if not os.path.exists(image):
                            input_miss.append(image)  
                            print image


                    else:
                        for miss in input_miss:
                            if os.path.exists(miss):
                                hash_miss = pHash.imagehash(miss)
                                print hash_miss + 'check on'
                                print >> create_file ,fileName+","+channelID+","+yearMonth+","+word[0]+","+str(hash_miss)+","+word[1].rstrip()+","+videoStart                  
                                input_miss.remove(miss)



            else:

                time.sleep(60) 

    #came out of loop
    conn.close()
```

I'm expecting value, and checking path for every image. My question is, how can I save variable in array when it's not true, and start process again on it when an image comes.

Comment: Um, maybe just use a second list and an `else` clause?

Comment: What is going on over here `print >> create_file,filename+","`?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why not just iterate over the input data and construct a list of the valid images?

Comment: Its server expecting path's, and reading if path is true make hash on image, but when path is not true it wont go back and chech again for image.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid `create_file` might be a file-like object in which case that line's fine (it's the Python 2.x equiv of `print('whatever', 'whatever', file=create_file)`)

Comment: If the path doesn't exist, then what should happen?

Comment: Thanks @JonClements I have never come across that _in Python_

Comment: Wow, after the update to the code .... I am not sure where to begin.

Comment: Wha do you mean about print? Can you show example to me.